# MS Bot Framework - Timing Issues

Tags: botframework

I have noticed this somewhat infrequently but definitely enough to be a problem. If you type ahead, anticipating questions you know will come up, the bot sometimes will answer questions out of order. For example, let's say you have a pizza ordering bot that responds to "I want to order a pizza" and the first question to that is always "What size pizza?"

Let's say there is a dialog called RootDialog and OrderPizzaDialog. Normal flow would be:

```
Bot: starts in RootDialog
User: "I want to order a pizza"
User: "Large"
Bot: forwards to OrderPizzaDialog
Bot: "What size pizza?"
Bot: "Ok, one large pizza..."
... bunch of pizza options, pizza is ordered ...
Bot: returns to RootDialog
```

But sometimes when you type fast "I want to order a pizza" and then type "large" immediately after, not always, but maybe 1 out of every 15 times this happens:

```
Bot: starts in RootDialog
User: "I want to order a pizza"
User: "large"
Bot: still in RootDialog for some reason "I don't understand 'large'"
Bot: forwards to OrderPizzaDialog
Bot: "What size pizza?"
User: "large" ( had to answer large again because somehow the first large went to RootDialog )
Bot: "Ok, one large pizza..."
... bunch of pizza options, pizza is ordered ...
Bot: returns to RootDialog
```

I understand how this can happen with asynch web.api calls, however with a chat bot framework I would expect some extra handling to ensure that users input is handled in the order they type. An input count or something being tracked and sent to the web.api handler to make sure it waits for messages it hasn't gotten yet. Is this not handled in MS Bot Framework?

Comment: In "[How can I guarantee message delivery order?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#how-can-i-guarantee-message-delivery-order)" section, we can find: *`The Bot Framework will preserve message ordering as much as possible. However, in general, message delivery order cannot be guaranteed since the channel is ultimately responsible for message delivery and may reorder messages. To mitigate the risk of messages being delivered in the wrong order, you might choose to implement a time delay between messages.`*

Comment: Thanks Fei. Any recommendations on where to put in a delay? MessageController or IActivityLogger? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

A bot is just a web application. If it is important to your bot that all messages are processed in the order received, then you cannot scale the bot sideways to multiple servers, unless you also have some sort of intelligent message broker between the connectors and the bot servers.  Most bots are just written in a way that message order does not matter, or out of order messages are discarded and ignored.

That said, the .NET sdk does ensure that messages received by the bot are queued and processed in the order received.  There is a class called **LocalMutualExclusion** here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/cb431b52043847544a7050844d8190a2afea5fa2/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Base/Scope.cs#L58  It has a Semaphore for each active conversation the bot is currently processing and only allows one activity to be processed per conversation.

Comment: Well, it's not really "just" a web application. It's a chat bot framework, supposedly. Handling order in a single server scenario would certainly be possible, and even adding in support for a message broker would also be possible. I think the answer is that this just has not been implemented for this framework. Thanks for you insight on the locking.

Comment: I am curious though about your comment. Are you aware of any real world chat bot scenarios that do not care what order messages are processed in? I mean I guess I can see how in real life if you talked to a person and fired a bunch of questions off they wouldn't necessarily answer in order. But is that the behavior we are trying to mimic with chat bots?